# Out of Memory issue iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, instruments, allocation

In my iOS app I am running the instruments tool to see the memory allocated. In the app I call CoreData and use that to create a survey using Apple's ResearchKit. Every time I run a new one I see an increase in the amount of 'persistant bytes' increases. When the app is run, whenever it is run multiple time over and over eventually the app closes.

I can see using Fabric's Crashylitics that a Out of Memory session occurred.

[image: Here you can see the jumps and the allocations remain]
What's the best way to go about finding and fixing the memory that seems to be retained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot is not showing any memory leaks so you should start by using the Allocations instrument, the graph of which is in your screenshot.

Start by setting an inspection range where the memory usage spikes. Click in the graph and drag to set the inspection range. You will notice that the graph color outside the inspection range changes to gray. At this point you have focus on where the memory usage spikes.

To find the place in your code that's causing the increase in memory usage, switch to the call tree view by clicking in the jump bar below the graph and choosing Call Trees. Inverting the call tree and hiding system libraries makes it much easier to find your code in the call tree. Click the Call Tree button at the bottom of the window to invert the call tree and hide system libraries.

[image]

If you find a function in the call tree that is allocating a lot of memory, you can double-click it to show the lines of code that are allocating the memory.

Another tool you can use to analyze memory growth is the Allocations instrument's generations. Run your app, pause, and click the Mark Generation button to create a generation. Repeat to create multiple generations. Choose Generations from the jump bar to see how much memory growth you have from generation to generation.